# Get a balance of an address at a certain block

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, balances

We are facing a problem with the `web3.eth.getBalance(address [, defaultBlock] [, callback])` ( [here the doc](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#getbalance) ). The function works well for last block, or for a small number of blocks in the past, but it does not returns ( it apparently hangs ) for block deeper in the history. What's the reason of this behavior?

Comment: what is the sync mode you are using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The balance of an address is stored in the "Ethereum World State", this state is updated in each block registering changes produced by the processed transactions.

To return the balance at a block number your node needs to have the world state at that block.

Since querying for balances at old block is very uncommon operation new versions of geth started to remove old version of the world state to save space on disk.

If you need access to balances in old blocks you will have to launch your node in 'archiving' mode. This mode uses a lot of disk space, close to 1TB recently.