# archive mode very slow

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization

I've a node that I'm trying to sync with:
`--syncomode "full" --gcmode "archive"` in order to address this needing [Get a balance of an address at a certain block](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/55272/21920)
Unfortunately things became soo slow that probably we never manage to have a synced node.
What can we use to optimize? I'm thinking on a pool of geth working together as a trusted peers cluster, would this work? Can be this created?

Comment: Are you using an SSD?

Comment: Yes on ebs on aws.

Comment: geth 1.7 was 30% slower , you are luck to start using ethereum from 1.8

Comment: your are probably processing right now a range from block 2.4M to 2.718M , there was an attack on Ethereum at that time wich makes `geth` run slowly

Comment: @Nulik indeed this hapen on the blocks you are saying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably processing right now a range from block 2.4M to 2.718M , there was an attack on Ethereum at that time which makes `geth` run slowly